# Label is not accepting AnchorLayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I wanted to trie out the anchor Layout unsing kivy language,but my Label was not affeckted by the AnchorLayout in any way

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

wurzel = Builder.load_string('''
AnchorLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'test'
        anchor_x:'left'
        anchor_y:'top'

''')
class TurF(App):

    def build(self):
        return wurzel

TurF().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The AnchorLayout is probably working fine, but your label fills it. Set something like the following instead.

```
AnchorLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'test'
        anchor_x:'left'
        anchor_y:'top'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 50, 50
```